# No Wi-Fi connection Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS / PCi Realtek

Tags: wireless, 22.04, realtek, realtek-wireless

I have brand new HP computer with windows installed and I dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Unfortunately there is no internet and I went through many instructions without results. What I have:

1. nmcli command:

```
    enp1s0: connected to Wired connection 1
            "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
            ethernet (r8169), 7C:57:58:5F:52:E5, hw, mtu 1500
            ip4 default
            inet4 192.168.1.13/24
            route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 100
            route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000
            route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 100
            inet6 fe80::f32e:43c8:a863:6ff1/64
            route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024
    
    lo: unmanaged
            "lo"
            loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
    
    DNS configuration:
            servers: 91.227.2.157 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
            interface: enp1s0
    
    Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
    "nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.
    
    Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.
```

2. lshw -C network command:

```
    *-network                 
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           logical name: enp1s0
           version: 15
           serial: 7c:57:58:5f:52:e5
           size: 100Mbit/s
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-45-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
           resources: irq:55 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fb604000-fb604fff memory:fb600000-fb603fff
      *-network UNCLAIMED
           description: Network controller
           product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
           version: 00
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fb500000-fb5fffff
    WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I would be very grateful for step by step explanation, cause I cannot use Ubuntu for like a week.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk |grep -iA3 net`

Answer (score 0):

If nmcli doesn't see the interface it might be a driver issue. You might get lucky and find there is a driver ready to install under Software & Updates > Additional Drivers.

Another thing to look at, actually under windows, is to go and un-tick any and all power saving options related to the wifi or bluetooth. The windows driver may be toggling off the device when it shuts down and then ubuntu doesn't have a way to turn it back on. I've seen HP laptops do that.

It looks like lshw doesn't see it either, that realtek device looks like your ethernet.

Another problem is sometimes you might have a conflicting kernel module that prevents the correct driver from loading. You need to know what device it is to approach solving that issue.

You might get an ID on the device with the lspci or the lsusb command.